# Date independent of system date in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I m trying to store dates in a column and then comparing it with the dates in other column. This excel will be used by different users with different date formats on their system. I tried to format the date from yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy/mm/dd but couldn't achieve it.

```
Columns("AC:AC").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd"
```

How to make it independent of the system?

Comment: store it as string instead of as date format

Comment: I m storing it as a string itslef.    dateArr = Array("4/1/2016", "4/15/2016", "5/1/2016", "5/15/2016", "6/1/2016", "6/15/2016", "7/1/2016", "7/15/2016", "8/1/2016", "8/15/2016", "9/1/2016", "9/15/2016", "10/1/2016", "10/15/2016", "11/1/2016", "11/15/2016", "12/1/2016", "12/15/2016")

Comment: i see. but thats an array variable, how do you put the values into the ranges? if you store the dates in the worksheet as string, probably you'll get warning that you are storing numbers as text, did you get this warning?

Comment: unless you have turned off the warning, then you might not see it. But if the warning is still turned on and you don't see it, then you are still storing the dates in the worksheet as date

Comment: No i dint get any such warning. Maybe because i m formatting the Range. I m using for loop to store the values. For i = 2 To UBound(dateArr)
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 26).Value = dateArr(i - 2) Next

Comment: Try Numberformat = "@"

Comment: Range("Z:Z").NumberFormat = "@"
    dateArr = Array("4/1/2016", "4/15/2016", "5/1/2016", "5/15/2016", "6/1/2016", "6/15/2016", "7/1/2016", "7/15/2016", "8/1/2016", "8/15/2016", "9/1/2016", "9/15/2016", "10/1/2016", "10/15/2016", "11/1/2016", "11/15/2016", "12/1/2016", "12/15/2016")
    For i = 2 To UBound(dateArr)
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 26).Text = dateArr(i - 2)
    Next

Comment: Its giving me an error. Unable to set the text property of range claas

Comment: sry i just noted that, use `.value` back

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working :)

Answer (score 1):

Date is stored as number in Excel. When opening a workbook, the dates will be displayed according to the regional setting of the user's pc.

To disconnect this regional auto-formatting, one way is to store the dates as "strings" or "text".

Use `Range.NumberFormat = "@"` to format a range as Text.

And then you may use `Range.Value = Format( <Date> , "yyyy/mm/dd")` to place the date String into the range with the required format.

If the range has not been pre-formatted as Text, and a string that looks like a date (e.g. "4/4/2016") is entered, Excel will assume its a date and convert it to the numeric representation. Had the range been formatted as Text, Excel will then ignore and assumes any input as a flat string, even numbers.